# How can I Validate the edit text and store the values in Android?

Tags: android, text, edit

I am creating one function inside the button and call the function outside.
When I click the button will call ...

Inside the function. Creating one Table layout and Table row. In the table row, I am creating edit text. How can I validate the edit text and store the values.

Suppose I am click the button first time means one edit text will displayed, after entering the values, then I click button another edit text will displayed etc... How can I store the values in array list. And also validate the edit text, if it null means the the button will not.

Answer (score 0):

Set your button disabled when there is edit text without any data i.e as soon as edit text is displayed

```
btn.setEnabled(false);
```

and enable in on

```
et.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            btn.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

where et is your editText

PS: Your question is not clear. The answer is just for what I understand.

Comment: Suppose i ve ten edit text, how can i store the  values in array list